# SocketTimeoutException while connecting to hbase on VB

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have my hbase installed in Ubuntu on Virtual Box. In Windows I have written a program in java to check if a table exists ?

```
@Test
public void checkTableExists() throws IOException
{
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.1.3");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.clientPort.property", "2181");
    conf.set("hbse.client.retries.number", "3");
    conf.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry", "2");

    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf); 

    Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();

    System.out.println(admin.tableExists(TableName.valueOf("test1")));

    admin.close();
    connection.close();

}
```

But I am not getting the output. Instead, I am getting this error:

17:52:05.661 [hconnection-0x5e2c3d18-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl - Use SIMPLE authentication for service ClientService, sasl=false
17:52:05.662 [hconnection-0x5e2c3d18-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:35899
17:52:06.668 [hconnection-0x5e2c3d18-shared--pool1-t1] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller - Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=58956 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=Connection refused: no further information row 'test1,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,35899,1512303024113, seqNum=0
17:52:06.670 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@71bbf57e testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6a41eaa2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
17:52:06.670 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@2e4b8173 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 2, missCount = 1]
17:52:06.671 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@71bbf57e testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6a41eaa2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
17:52:06.671 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@2e4b8173 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 3, missCount = 1]
17:52:06.673 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@71bbf57e testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6a41eaa2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
17:52:06.673 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@2e4b8173 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 4, missCount = 1]
17:52:06.673 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoBeans'
17:52:06.673 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@71bbf57e testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6a41eaa2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
17:52:06.674 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@2e4b8173 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 5, missCount = 1]
17:52:06.713 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@711f39f9 testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, testInstance = HbaseApplicationTest@184f6be2, testMethod = checkTableExists@HbaseApplicationTest, testException = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Sun Dec 03 17:52:06 IST 2017, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=79009: Connection refused: no further information row 'test1,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,35899,1512303024113, seqNum=0
, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@71bbf57e testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6a41eaa2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
17:52:07.202 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@711f39f9 testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@71bbf57e testClass = HbaseApplicationTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6a41eaa2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
17:52:07.232 [Thread-0] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@80503: startup date [Sun Dec 03 17:50:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
17:52:07.233 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
17:52:07.233 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5e57643e: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor$SpyPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002871/access-virtual-box-hbase-from-windows-java-application

Comment: I tried that. The master administration page opens in windows browser but Java is not able to access Hbase. :(